# MSSQL application failing to connect to database server

Tags: windows, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We run a very old application that connects to an MS SQL server 2008 database using the SQL server native client 10. Sometimes if there has been a power failure with the server the clients will stop communicating with the server. Normally in the past we have just uninstalled the SQL server native client and re-installed it and that would get things working again. This time it is not working. It seems to be a problem with the specific user profile on the client machine (Win 7 Pro). If I recreate the account everything works fine. On some clients there are user profiles that had not been logged into for more than three months that did not seem to be affected at all.

When the application is opened these windows pop up after hitting OK and cancel a few times. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGNyk.jpg

This is a trace done through the Data Sources (ODBC) module.

```
flogix          46c-115c    ENTER SQLAllocEnv 
        HENV *              0x10CD0CA4

flogix          46c-115c    EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV *              0x10CD0CA4 ( 0x01211630)

flogix          46c-115c    ENTER SQLAllocConnect 
        HENV                0x01211630
        HDBC *              0x0012EC84

flogix          46c-115c    EXIT  SQLAllocConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x01211630
        HDBC *              0x0012EC84 ( 0x012118C8)

flogix          46c-115c    ENTER SQLDriverConnectW 
        HDBC                0x012118C8
        HWND                0x0002030A
        WCHAR *             0x56288B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x56288B34 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        1 <SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE>

flogix          46c-115c    EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        HDBC                0x012118C8
        HWND                0x0002030A
        WCHAR *             0x56288B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x56288B34 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        1 <SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE>

flogix          46c-115c    ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x01211630

flogix          46c-115c    EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HENV                0x01211630

        DIAG [S1010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error (0) 

flogix          46c-115c    ENTER SQLAllocEnv 
        HENV *              0x10CD0CA4

flogix          46c-115c    EXIT  SQLAllocEnv  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV *              0x10CD0CA4 ( 0x01217B80)

flogix          46c-115c    ENTER SQLAllocConnect 
        HENV                0x01217B80
        HDBC *              0x0012EC84

flogix          46c-115c    EXIT  SQLAllocConnect  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
        HENV                0x01217B80
        HDBC *              0x0012EC84 ( 0x01217BF8)

flogix          46c-115c    ENTER SQLDriverConnectW 
        HDBC                0x01217BF8
        HWND                0x0002030A
        WCHAR *             0x56288B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x56288B34 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        1 <SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE>

flogix          46c-115c    EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code 100 (SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND)
        HDBC                0x01217BF8
        HWND                0x0002030A
        WCHAR *             0x56288B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
        SWORD                       -3 
        WCHAR *             0x56288B34 
        SWORD                       -3 
        SWORD *             0x00000000
        UWORD                        1 <SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE>

flogix          46c-115c    ENTER SQLFreeEnv 
        HENV                0x01217B80

flogix          46c-115c    EXIT  SQLFreeEnv  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
        HENV                0x01217B80

        DIAG [S1010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error (0)
```